# Form not submitting when valid data entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am building some validation but when I submit correct input it still shows as not valid, can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong!

The function works with invalid input but not with valid input

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
(function(){
var form      = '.contact-form',
    alert     = '.alert',
    fieldWrap = '.control-group',
    errorMsg  = '.error-message',
    error     = 'error',
    show      = 'show',
    hide      = 'hide';
var textField = function(){$(field).val() !== (regEx); return false};
var select    = function(){$(field + ' option:selected').val() === regEx; return false};
var validate  = function(ifParam,field,regEx,e){
    if(ifParam()){
        $(field).parents(fieldWrap).addClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(show);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $(field).parents(fieldWrap).removeClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(hide);
        return true;
    }
};
var valid = function(e){
    validate(textField,'#first-name'     ,/^[a-zA-Z]$/,e);
    validate(textField,'#last-name'      ,/^[a-zA-Z]$/,e);
    validate(textField,'#contact-number' ,/^[a-zA-Z]$/,e);
    validate(textField,'#email'          ,/^[a-zA-Z]$/,e);
    validate(textField,'#landline-number',/^[a-zA-Z]$/,e);
    validate(textField,'#postcode'       ,/^[a-zA-Z]$/,e);
    validate(select   ,'#title'          ,'select',e);
    return true;
};
$(document).on('submit',form,function(e){
    if(!valid()){
        $(alert).addClass(show);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else{
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    }
});
```

})();

Comment: what do you have in `regEx` ?

Comment: `$(this).unbind('submit');
$(this).submit();`

Comment: Your `textField` and `select` functions don't actually do anything - should they return a value?

Comment: they return the parameter for the if statement in the validate function

Comment: But they don't have a `return` statement. Also your if statement should be `if(ifParam()){` not `if(ifParam){` (without the `()` you don't call the function and your if statement will always be true). Also you pass a regex to the `validate()` function but it doesn't do anything with it - it should pass it to `ifParam()`.

Comment: ifParam() isn't a function but calls either textField or select functions where regEx is being passed through?!? passing parameters and functions around is a bit confusing for me :-(

Comment: If you could add an answer with some code and explination that would be greatly appreciated